# Due: Write to digital pin when ADC is running

Tags: adc

I have a problem writing to a digital pin on Arduino Due while my ADC is running.

I have the following code:

```
 #undef HID_ENABLED

// Arduino Due ADC->DMA->USB 1MSPS
// by stimmer
// from http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=137635.msg1136315#msg1136315
// Input: Analog in A0
// Output: Raw stream of uint16_t in range 0-4095 on Native USB Serial/ACM

// on linux, to stop the OS cooking your data: 
// stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke -onlcr

// source: https://gist.github.com/pklaus/5921022
// applied patch 1 from: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=137635.msg2526475#msg2526475
// applied patch 2 from:  https://gist.github.com/pklaus/5921022 comment on Apr 2, 2017 from borisbarbour

volatile int bufn,obufn;
uint16_t buf[4][256];    // 4 buffers of 256 readings

void ADC_Handler(){     // move DMA pointers to next buffer
  int f=ADC->ADC_ISR;
  if (f&(1<<27)){
   bufn=(bufn+1)&3;
   // patch 2 start
   //ADC->ADC_RNPR=(uint32_t)buf[bufn];
   ADC->ADC_RNPR=(uint32_t)buf[(bufn+1)&3];
   // patch 2 end
   ADC->ADC_RNCR=256;
  } 
}

void setup() {
  SerialUSB.begin(0);
  while(!SerialUSB);

  pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_ADC);
  adc_init(ADC, SystemCoreClock, ADC_FREQ_MAX, ADC_STARTUP_FAST);
  ADC->ADC_MR |=0x80; // free running

  ADC->ADC_CHER=0x80; 

  NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
  ADC->ADC_IDR=~(1<<27);
  ADC->ADC_IER=1<<27;
  ADC->ADC_RPR=(uint32_t)buf[0];   // DMA buffer
  ADC->ADC_RCR=256;
  ADC->ADC_RNPR=(uint32_t)buf[1]; // next DMA buffer
  ADC->ADC_RNCR=256;
  // patch 1.2 start
  //bufn=obufn=1;
  bufn=1;
  obufn=0;
  // patch 1.2 end
  ADC->ADC_PTCR=1;
  ADC->ADC_CR=2;

  // this doesn't work:
  pinMode(52, OUTPUT); // 
  digitalWrite(52, HIGH); //
}

void loop(){
  // patch 1.1 start
  while((obufn + 1)%4==bufn);// wait for buffer to be full
  // patch 1.1 end
  SerialUSB.write((uint8_t *)buf[obufn],512); // send it - 512 bytes = 256 uint16_t
  obufn=(obufn+1)&3;    
}
```

Pin 52 says 0 V.

With this function, I can pull the digital output voltage to 1.58 V:

```
void digitalWriteDirect(int pin, boolean val){
  if(val) g_APinDescription[pin].pPort -> PIO_SODR = g_APinDescription[pin].ulPin;
  else    g_APinDescription[pin].pPort -> PIO_CODR = g_APinDescription[pin].ulPin;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: The Arduino had been waiting for the `SerialUSB` Connection.

The Serial connection has not been established because I was running the Arduino without running the corresponding Python script. That script would have opened the Serial connection.

When running the Python script, the Arduino Due then works as expected.